# What is the motivation behind inventing Closures in Topology?

Tags: general-topology

I am studying Topology from Munkres and in Section 17 he says how we could have studied this subject using closed sets instead of open sets, and later comes the introduction to Closure of a set. I am curious to know why was this concept of closure "invented" - what does it help us in studying? Is there an "equivalent form for open-sets"?

Comment: Both open and closed sets in topology are derived from open and close *intervals* of the real number line.

Comment: Sort of like asking, what was the point of inventing rocks in geology? Closure isn't something that was invented **in** topology, it's what topology is **about**. A **topological space** is a set $X$ of points equipped with a **closure operator** $\operatorname{cl}:\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(X)$ satisfying the Kuratowski closure axioms.

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept similar to closure which I'm sure  you already know of - interior. While closure of a set $A$ is the smallest closed set that contains $A$, the interior of $A$ is the largest open set that is contained in $A$.

Closed sets and closure of sets are later useful in treating compact sets, especially in metric spaces.

Closure of a set is also useful in checking if a subset of a set is dense in it. If $A$ is a subset of $X$ then $A$ is said to be dense in $X$ if the closure of $A$ is $X$. This means that any element in $X$ can be approximated as accurately as desired with elements in $A$. You would have already studied that every irrational number has a decimal representation. Any truncated version of this representation is a rational number and is a good approximation of the irrational number. So we say that the set of rational numbers is dense in the set of real numbers.

Further, perhaps more importantly, the closure of a set contains all the elements that are closest to points in the set. You would not have this advantage if you had something like "open closure" (i.e. the smallest open set that contains a set). So a closure of a set is a good box that contains a given set.

Comment: You wrote "the interior of A is the largest open set that is contained in A." I changed it to "largest". I'm sure it was just a typo.

Comment: infinitesimal here makes no sense

Comment: @janmarqz Fair enough. I have changed "infinitesimally close"  to "closest". I hope this is clearer.